# Any package to do 3D slam with kinect in ROS fuerte

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, kinect, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with hector_slam and I get 2D slam. I want learn to do 3D slam can somebody help me with any package to ROS fuerte and some instructions?

Best regards people.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205386/any-package-to-do-3d-slam-with-kinect-in-ros-fuerte/) by [Rookie92](https://answers.ros.org/users/18371/rookie92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2015-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look into the [rgbd_slam](http://wiki.ros.org/rgbdslam) package to do 3d slam using rgbd sensor like kinect. I am not sure if its currently maintained(fuerte version) since there is a new version of [RGBDSLAM v2](http://felixendres.github.io/rgbdslam_v2/) for indigo and hydro already out. If you have problems you should better contact the developers of rgbd_slam package.

Apart from that there is an [octomap](http://wiki.ros.org/octomap) package that builds 3d occupancy grid maps. The map implementation is based on an octree.

---

Originally posted by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) with karma: 654 on 2015-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1